# Joining two SQL tables based on the equality of few columns

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

I am trying to Create a SQL View by joining two SQL tables and return only the lowest value from second table and all the rows from first table similar to left join.

My problem can be clearly explained with the below example.

**Table1**

```
Id  Product Grade Term Bid Offer 
100 ABC       A   Q1   10  20
101 ABC       A   Q1   5   25
102 XYZ       A   Q2   25  30
103 XYZ       B   Q2   20  30
```

**Table2**

```
Id Product Grade Term TradeValue
1  ABC     A     Q1     100
2  ABC     A     Q1     95    
3  XYZ     B     Q2     100
```

In the above data I want to join `Table1` and `Table2` when ever the columns `Product,Grade and Term` from both the tables are equal and return all the rows from `Table1` while joining the lowest Value of the column `TradeValue` from `Table2` to the first record of the match and making `TradeValue as NULL` for other rows of the resultant View and the resultant View should have the `Id` of `Table2` as `LTID`

So the resultant SQL View should be

**RESULT**

```
   Id  Product Grade Term Bid Offer TradeValue LTID
   100  ABC       A   Q1   10   20     95         2
   101  ABC       A   Q1   5    25    NULL        2
   102  XYZ       A   Q2   25   30    NULL       NULL
   103  XYZ       B   Q2   20   30    100         3
```

I tried using the following query

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ViewCC]
AS
SELECT
a.Id,a.Product,a.Grade,a.Term,a.Bid,a.Offer,
b.TradeValue
FROM Table1 AS a 
left  JOIN (SELECT Product,Grade,Term,MIN(TradeValue) TradeValue from  Table2 Group by Product,Grade,Term,) AS b
 ON  b.Product=a.Product
and b.Grade=a.Grade
and b.Term=a.Term 
GO
```

The above Query returned the following data which is apt to the query I wrote but that is not what I was trying to get

```
 Id  Product Grade Term Bid Offer TradeValue 
 100   ABC      A   Q1   10   20      95       
 101   ABC      A   Q1   5    25      95 --This should be null     
 102   XYZ      A   Q2   25   30     NULL     
 103   XYZ      B   Q2   20   30     100
```

As we can see minimum value of `TradeValue` being assigned to all matching rows in `Table1` and also I was not able to return `Id As LTID` from Table2 as I have issues with `group by` clause as I cannot group it by **b.Id** as it returns too many rows.

**May I know a better way to deal with this?**

Comment: "while joining the lowest Value of the column TradeValue from Table2 to the first record of the match and making TradeValue as NULL for other rows of the resultant View" 

What do you mean by "first record"? Do you mean the record with the lowest value in the ID column?

Comment: Yes, Lowest value of the ID column in Table1 from the data that match with Table2 (Product,Grade and Term) Like in my expected results record with ID 100 and 101 in Table1 match with ID 1 and 2 in Table2 so I got the minimum value of Tradevalue 95 and asigned it with the record with ID 100 in table 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a row number attached to each record from `Table1`, so that the requirement of only joining the first record from each group of `Table1` can be fulfilled:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ViewCC]
AS
SELECT a.Id, a.Product, a.Grade, a.Term, a.Bid, a.Offer, 
       b.TradeValue, b.Id AS LTID
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Product, Grade, Term ORDER BY Id) AS rn
  FROM Table1
) a
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN TradeValue
                    ELSE NULL
               END AS TradeValue, Id 
  FROM  Table2
  WHERE Product=a.Product AND Grade=a.Grade AND Term=a.Term
  ORDER BY TradeValue) b  
GO
```

`OUTER APPLY` returns a table expression containing either the matching record from `Table2` with the lowest `TradeValue`, or `NULL` if no matching record exists.

Comment: Well the above query works well for returning Id from Table2 but it still returns lowest value for all matching records but what I want if there are multiple matching records then also I want to return to the lowest TradeValue only for the first matching record and NULL for remaining matching records. Please refer to RESULT in my question where there are two records matching for the first row in Table2 if with ID 100 and 101 matches with ID 1 in Table 1 so result should be two rows from Table1 but lowest trade value(95) is assigned only to ID100 and other is made NULL also respective LTID=NULL

Comment: @Dev Yes you are right. I just misread the requirements of the OP. Have a look at the edit i made. It should work now.

Comment: I am sorry but what if I want the LTID not null for the second match instead it should point to same value as its first record as I edited in my Question in result section

Comment: @Dev You can do whatever you like inside the `OUTER APPLY` clause, as long as you have `rn` at hand. Have a look at the edit I made